# Function arguments + shell

Tags: vimscript, external-command, functions

I'm trying to write a command for adding a Python import line. The problem is that what's added it `import a:name` and not the module name.

Here's the code

```
func! PyImport(name)
    w
    silent !isort -q -a a:name %
    e
endfunc
comm! -nargs=1 PyImport call PyImport(<f-args>)
```

I guess I need to someone expand `a:name`, couldn't find how to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
silent execute('!isort -q -a ' . a:name . ' ' . expand("%:p"))
```

This executes the given string. The `expand("%:p")` creates the fully qualified file name for the current file.

BTW: I would recommend to add `set autoload` before executing and `set noautoload` after it. That way the file will automatically be reloaded after execute. No need for `e` then.